# C# socket program auto close

Tags: c#, sockets, c#-4.0

When I use this program to socket a range of IP address, it's always closed by itself for some time without any message. The program just ends. How can I fix this problem? (It is a console project)

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task[] tasks = new Task[200];
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
    {
        tasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => RunningThread());
    }
    Task.WaitAll(tasks);
    Console.WriteLine("finish...");
    Console.ReadKey();
    //.....
}

public bool SocketIP(string ip, int port)
{
    AutoResetEvent arEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    if (socket != null)
    {
        socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0));
        socket.BeginConnect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), port), CallBack, new ArrayList() { socket, arEvent});
        arEvent.WaitOne(WaitTime);
        if (Rv)
            socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        socket.Close();
        socket = null;
    }
    return Rv;
}


void CallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    ArrayList list = (ArrayList)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket socket = (Socket)list[0];

    AutoResetEvent arevent = (AutoResetEvent)list[1];

    if (ar.IsCompleted && socket.Connected)
        Rv = true;
    arevent.Set();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way your code looks it should stop at Console.ReadKey(). Maybe there is a crash unhandled in the program. Try putting a Try catch around the complete main function en debug on the Exception ex.
I mean like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
try{
    Task[] tasks = new Task[200];
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
    {
        tasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => RunningThread());
    }
    Task.WaitAll(tasks);
    Console.WriteLine("finish...");
    Console.ReadKey();
    //.....
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
 Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); <<<--(break point here)
}
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my bad describe.Actually in the main function , i write down a Try catch  to get it.But no one debug it is useful.Try catch can not catch any Exception.Is this ex not belong to Try catch exception?

Comment: Try running it from a command line allready opened. Then the command stays open and maybe shows a message...

Comment: It works well in command.Er....maybe this condition just my mistake.Any way,thank for your help and sorry for waste your time for my mistake.

Comment: Well it should stop normally on the ReadKey. so it it a little weird